Bytearrays not being imported as expected into PIO OSR via DMA in Micropython
This is the setup I'm trying to get working:
On a Pi Pico I have set up a PIO StateMachine. It's FIFO TX is fed by a DMA Channel.
The StateMachine pulls from the FIFO to the OSR (this should always be 32 bits) and triggers a pulse on pin 15 of the Pico. It then shifts out 16 bits from the OSR to the x register. This is used to create a delay in the code using a loop.
As the OSR holds 32 bits and only 16 have been shifted out it then checks if the OSR still holds data. if it does, it triggers another pulse, shifts in the remaining 16 bits and repeats the whole process until the DMA channel is done.
here's the code of the StateMachine and the attached DMA channel:
StateMachine:
@asm_pio(set_init=PIO.OUT_LOW, out_init=PIO.OUT_LOW, autopull=False)
def pio_pacer():
    pull(block)
    label("rep")
    set(pins, 1)
    set(pins, 0)
    out(x, 16)
    label("delay")
    jmp(x_dec, "delay")
    jmp(not_osre, "rep")

DMA-Channel:
timer_dma = DMA()
timer_dma_ctrl = timer_dma.pack_ctrl(size=2, inc_read=True, inc_write=False, treq_sel=DREQ_PIO0_TX0)

timer_dma.config(
    read=pio_data,
    write=PIO0_BASE_TXF0,
    count=int(len(pio_data)/4),
    ctrl=timer_dma_ctrl,
    trigger=True
)

The statemachine and DMA-Channel seem to be set up (mostly) correctly as they do "work through" the data - pins get signals and the process finishes without an error.
The problem seems to be the bytearray that forms the basis of the data sent to the PIO via the DMA-Channel.
The data is created by using a list of integers. Those integers represent the number of cycles the StateMachine is supposed to wait between pulses. These are the values that I want to pass to the x register for the delay loop. All integer values range from about 10_000 down to aproximately 800 - so they never exeede 16 bits in length.
As far as I know the DMA needs its data as a bytearray.
The datastruction of the bytearray looks something like bytearray(b'\xff\xfe') for two entries of (255, 254). I need it to hold numbers that are not 8 but 16 bits long, so I use two consecutive entries to store the integer values from my list.
This is how I convert the int list to a bytearray:
int_list = (10000, 8532, 7632, 1435, 810) # example of numbers in int_list
pio_data = bytearray(5*2) # empty array, 5 is number of entries in the int_list example
for i in range(5):
    pio_data[2*i] = int((y[i] - (y[i] % 256))/256)
    pio_data[2*i+1] = int(y[i] % 256)

This way I turn large integers like 7632 into \x1d\xd0 in the bytearray. printing the bytearray shows that this indeed works:
bytearray(b"'\x10!T\x1d\xd0\x05\x9b\x03*")
Keep in mind that the micropython terminal on the Pi Pico automatically converts bytes into unicode, so the output looks a bit wonky... Translated into a "readable" bytearray it looks like this - the numbers have been converted correctly:
bytearray(b"\x27\x10\x21\x54\x1d\xd0\x05\x9b\x03\x2a")
Now I have my bytearray prepared and I should be able to send the first 16 bits to the PIO. In our case this is 2710 (in Hex) or 10,000 (in Int).
Weird thing is: It does not seem to work as expected. Checking with an LED driven by the PIO it should show the LED starting very dim (long delays), and ending bright (short delays) - but thats not what I see. The LED "pulses" more or less randomly.
I checked the status of the DMA-Channel with DMA.count and it shows that the channel is worked on pretty much as I expect. The numbers that get shifted to the x register on the PIO can't be correct though...
Note: The int_list used in the actual code is much, much longer (1600 to 3200 entries). That's not the issue either, as the error is independent of the length of the list and even at 3200 there is plenty of free memory left.
Any ideas where I went wrong are greatly appreciated.
